# How to use Polaris

Tags: javascript, dependency-management, pageload, page-load-time, polaris

Recently, a lot of sites have published about [Polaris](http://web.mit.edu/ravinet/www/polaris_nsdi16.pdf):

> #### Polaris: Faster Page Loads Using Fine-grained Dependency Tracking
>
> [...]
>
> We introduce Polaris, a dynamic client-side scheduler that is written
>   in JavaScript and runs on unmodified browsers; using a fully automatic
>   compiler, servers can translate normal pages into ones that load
>   themselves with Polaris. Polaris uses fine-grained dependency graphs
>   to dynamically determine which objects to load, and when. Since
>   Polaris’ graphs have no missing edges, Polaris can aggressively fetch
>   objects in a way that minimizes network round trips. Experiments in a
>   variety of network conditions show that Polaris decreases page load
>   times by 34% at the median, and 59% at the 95th percentile.
>
> [...]

But I just couldn't find it anywhere.

Did anybody find / use / test it?

Comment: See also [nsdi'16](https://www.usenix.org/conference/nsdi16/technical-sessions/presentation/netravali) and [MIT News](http://news.mit.edu/2016/system-loads-web%20pages-34-percent-faster-0309)